# Find the $\sigma$-algebra that makes the following map a measure($X=\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: measure-theory

$v(A)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{if $A$ is finite} \\
      1 & \text{if $A^c$ is finite} \\
   \end{cases} $

This is a basic question and I don't think $P(\mathbb{Q})$ is a desired $\sigma$-algebra, nor are $P(\mathbb{R})$ and $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$. Any idea?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Well, I don't think the answer is in the form of power set, because power series of real and rational doesn't hold. I think the desired set  is described piece-wise but I have no idea

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ makes $\nu$ a measure. We have $\nu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\nu(\mathbb{R})=1$.  The point is that $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ is not the only $\sigma$-algebra that makes $\nu$ a measure.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering $X=\mathbb{R}$, you want to find the $\sigma$-algebras that make the following map a measure:
$\nu(A)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{if $A$ is finite} \\
      1 & \text{if $A^c$ is finite} \\
   \end{cases} $

Note that there are more than one such $\sigma$-algebra.

$1$. Let $\Sigma$ be any $\sigma$-algebra generated by a finite collection of finite subsets of $\Bbb R$. That means there is $\{F_i\}_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}}$ where each $F_i$ is finite and
$\Sigma = \sigma(\{F_i\}_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}})$.

It is straight forward to check that $\nu$ is a measure defined on $\Sigma$.

$2$. Suppose $\Sigma$ is $\sigma$-algebra such that $\nu$ is measure defined on $\Sigma$.

First, if $E \in \Sigma$ is any infinite set, then $E^c$ is finite. In fact, if $E$ is a infinite set and $E^c$ is not finite, $\nu$ is not defined for $E$, which is a contradiction to the fact that $\nu$ is defined on $\Sigma$.

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{F \in \Sigma : F \textrm { is finite }\}$. From the previous paragraph, it follows immediately that $\Sigma = \sigma(\mathcal{F})$.

Second, let us prove that the set $\mathcal{F}$ is a finite collection.

**Proof**: Suppose  $\mathcal{F}$ is infinite and let $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be a countably infinite subset of $\mathcal{F}$. Then $E=\bigcup_{F\in \mathcal{F}_1}F\in \Sigma$ is infinite. So, we know that $E^c$ is finite, and then we have
$$1= \nu(E) = \nu \left (\bigcup_{F\in \mathcal{F}_1}F \right) \leqslant \sum_{F\in \mathcal{F}_1} \nu(F)=0 $$
Contradiction.  $\square$

Combining $1$ and $2$ above we have that $\nu$ is a measure defined on the  $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ if and only if $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra generate by a finite collection of finite subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you explain what it means by "generated by finite number of finite subsets"? I only learned $\sigma$-algebra generated by one subset, which is basically the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing that set, but not generated by multiple sets. I'm new to this concept so sorry if this is too basic.

Comment: @able20 , $\sigma$-algebras are generated by a collection of subsets of the domain (in the current case $\Bbb R$). For instance, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the collection of **open** subsets of $\Bbb R$. 

In some situations, to make the sentence lighter we simply write "the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the  open subsets of $\Bbb R$". We leave "collection of" implicit. 

In the same way, "$\sigma$-algebra generated by finite number of finite subsets" means "$\sigma$-algebra generated by a finite collection of finite subsets".

Comment: That makes sense. I was somehow mixed up with "set of finite number of subsets" and "finite set."  Thanks!

Comment: @able20 , I have edited my answer in three point to explicitly include the word "collection".  I hope it is now clearer.